# ping general failure when routing VPN

Tags: routes, vpn, static-ip-address

I have a UDP listener on windows server 2008 r2 that receives packets from remote devices and responds to them.

Also I have a SQL Server 2008 on a remote server which I insert data received. The only way to get to this server is through a VPN.

I have a static IP on my listener. I need to respond to the devices through this IP.

When I connect to the VPN and respond to the devices, the tracert goes through the VPN and through the external IP of the VPN, therefore the device ignores the response. I need to route the ip tables so every IP except the local ones (192.168.0.X).

I tried several configuration but I always end up without internet, or exiting through the VPN. 
This configuration "seems" right for me, but doesn't work. I understand here that every ip should exit through gateway 190.12.113.233 but a general failure error happens and I don't know what to do now.

The static IP interface is set up with the dns 8.8.8.8.

[image: route print]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me a few times and I solved it by doing  `ipconfig /flushdns` or restarting windows.